# How to interpret line in sudoers

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, raspbian

Lets say I was told to do sudoers file changes with the following... What does that mean, and how do I actually do it?

```
www-data        ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/rm /etc/vsftpd/vusers/[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I believe that it's setting the premissions for those folders, and I think I use the `visudo` command to do it... but I'm not sure what the `www-data` means or anything like that. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word in the line indicates who this line applys to.  www-data is a user, you can find it in /etc/passwd.

NOPASSWD means members of this user doesn't have to authenticate when calling sudo.  Mostly used when a process will be calling sudo instead of a human.

The next part is the what your www-data has access to.

So this line means that the user www-data can execute /bin/rm on the files found in /etc/vsftpd/vusers/[a-zA-Z0-9]* as root without supplying their password.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all of that! So then in order to change this, I believe i should use visudo, which I believe is a a safe way of editing the /etc/sudoers file correct? would the steps be login as root, send visudo command, and then past the "www-data    All=nopassws: /bin...." line into the file and then save it? looking at the sudoers file right now, that looks correct, but I just wanted to make sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @gerrgheiser visudo will call your default editor.  Simply  ssh in as a user, use `sudo -i` to become root, set your default editor and launch visudo - I like joe so I do `root@host ~ # EDITOR=/usr/bin/joe visudo`.  The `/etc/sudoers` file is plain text so any editor will work - `visudo` is a wrapper to whatever your $EDITOR variable is set to (or system default) that copies the file, runs your editor on it, checks your edited copy for syntax correctness, and if all is good it saves the file back to `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: The answer above is mostly correct. However, it doesn't show that the user can "access /bin/rm/ AND /etc/vsftpd/vusers/[a-zA-Z0-9]*". It means that the user can EXECUTE `/bin/rm` but ONLY against essentially any file underneath '/etc/vsftpd/vusers/'. However, the files must only contain upper or lowercase letters and numbers.